# IE7/IE8 in Compatibility mode DIV with overflow problem

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, overflow, html

I have a scrollable div on a page that ends up rendering past the bottom of div and sometimes leaves stick characters behind that don't scroll. This happens in IE7 and IE8 in compatibility mode.

Here is the HTML code from the DOM:

```
<DIV id=ctl00_MainContent_ViewPort class=AgreementViewPort><IMG class=PortSeal src="/images/Seal.png">
<DIV class=DocumentTitle>Document Title</DIV>
<OL>
<LI>Condition #1</LI>
<LI>Condition #2<SUP>1</SUP></LI>
<LI>Condition #3</LI>
<DL>
<DT><SUP>1</SUP> some foot-noted definition.</DT></DL></DIV>
```

Here's the applied CSS style:

```
color: #000;
font-family: arial, tahoma, sans-serif
font-size: 12pt;
height: 300px;
margin: 5px;
overflow: scroll;
padding : 5px;
width: 600px;
```

This renders fine under IE8, Firefox, and Chrome.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could create a small test case showing the problem on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com). Or, at least provide more of the surrounding HTML (and not the IE munged version).

Comment: The primary reason for the IE munged version is the javascript fills out the contents of the div from an AJAX call to load the agreement. I'll see if I can build a repro case on JS Bin.

Comment: If it's really hard to get a test case going, screenshots might help instead. Also, this sounds really weird: "sometimes leaves stick characters behind that don't scroll".

Comment: First, your markup is not valid. Where is ol element closed?

Comment: The IE7 DOM removed the closing </ol>. It's in the source XML where the content of the scrollable dive is stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've solved the mystery.

If you want to poke at the issue directly, here's where it can be seen [live](http://www.emodal.com/AllUsers/PortAgreement.aspx?port=POBCompany). *Note: After we push the fix, this link won't repro.*

On the LI element in the page level CSS, I removed the following style attributes

```
li
{
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        position: relative;
        left: 10px;
        width: 500px;
}
```

And replaced them with:

```
li
{
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 25px;
}
```

On the OL element in the page level CSS, the width attribute was moved.

```
ol 
    {
        padding-left: 10px;
        width: 500px;
    }
```

And I feel like something of an idiot. The moral of the story, and this has been discussed elsewhere is that IE7 scrollable divs and the CSS position attribute do not play well together.

Answer (score 0):

Just by looking I'd suggest putting the image in its own DIV. This way you can control any overflows.

Also add the following to your CSS:

```
clip:rect(0px,600px,300px,0px);
```

Comment: I added the clip to the CSS, see below, but it's getting ignored.

    .AgreementViewPort
    {
        overflow: scroll;
        width: 600px;
        height: 300px;
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        clip:rect(0px,600px,300px,0px); 
    }